# Static Variable NullPointerException

Tags: android, static, nullpointerexception

I tried to access a static variable and I am getting a Nullpointerexception only for a few users I found in analytics:­

```
public class Regex {
    public static final String
    MY_REGEX="\\S+(\\s+\\S+){7}\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+.*";
    public static Pattern MY_PTRN = Pattern.compile(MY_REGEX);
}
```

//

```
public class SomeClass{
   If(somestring!=null){
      Matcher matcher = Regex.MY_PTRN.matcher(somestring);
      // Nullpointerexception
   }
}
```

I am no java expert. Should I be accessing the static variable differently ?

Comment: Check with your Imports...of Regex,Matcher   ... no issue in your code

Comment: java.util.regex.Matcher

Comment: If you debug properly, you'll know exactly where things are going wrong!

Comment: As i said I found the exception in analytics for a few users. No trace available. Locally cannot reproduce.

Comment: nothing wrong with that code

Answer (score 0):

I am not a `Java` expert too. General way of accessing a static variable is as follows:

```
public class Regex { 
     static final String MY_REGEX;
    MY_REGEX="\\S+(\\s+\\S+){7}\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+.*";
   } 

public class SomeClass{
   somestring=Regex.MY_REGEX
   If(somestring!=null){
      //do something witht the string.
}
}
```

Comment: So this would mean compiling the Pattern every time ?  I want the Pattern to be compiled once on access and available thereafter every time I use it.

Comment: matcher() method of Pattern does return a new instance of Matcher

Comment: if matcher is a method then you have to compile pattern everytime.